# Automatically disable HorizontalScrollView when content small enough

Tags: android, android-viewpager, horizontalscrollview

I use a `HorizontalScrollView` to contain a bunch of dynamic `TextView` elements. They are dropped into a `LinearLayout` container that is the only child of the scroll view:

```
<HorizontalScrollView android:id="@+id/outline_container"
                      android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"                          
                      android:scrollbars="none"
                      android:requiresFadingEdge="horizontal"
                      android:fadingEdgeLength="16dp">

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/outline"
                  android:orientation="horizontal"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

This is to ensure that if (and only if) there's more text than the available width can show, the user can scroll horizontally through the texts.

BUT: in many, many cases, the texts are short enough to be shown on screen. The `LinearLayout` container with id `outline` thus fits completely within the `HorizontalScrollView`.

Problem is: horizontal swipe gestures are still caught but should not be, because the whole thing is within a `ViewPager` which itself would like to handle the horizontal swipes!

I am looking for a solution that enables this `HorizontalScrollView`'s scrolling *only* if the room for the contents is too limited.

Answer (score 0):

In order to prevent the HorizontalScrollView from scroll, you have to override the onTouchEvent method to return false. That led me to create my own HSV like so:

```
public class MyHorizontalScrollView extends HorizontalScrollView{


    boolean tooSmall = true;

    public MyHorizontalScrollView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyHorizontalScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyHorizontalScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    public void setTooSmall(boolean tooSmall){
        this.tooSmall = tooSmall;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        if(tooSmall)
            return false;
        else
            return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
    }
}
```

Then, after you replace your HSV with this custom view, you need monitor the size of your LinearLayout(R.id.outline) to see if it is smaller or larger than your HSV. Adding this snippet helped me achieve that goal.

```
ll = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.outline);
hsv = (MyHorizontalScrollView) view.findViewById(R.id.outline_container);
ll.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {

            Log.d("widths", ll.getWidth() + " : " + hsv.getWidth());
            hsv.setTooSmall(ll.getWidth() < hsv.getWidth());
        }
});
```